# In the new Elmish.WPF 4.0 beta version, where is runWindowWithConfig?

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

I've been playing with the new beta version of Elmish.WPF 4.0 and can't seem to find
Program.runWindowWithConfig. Has it been replaced?

```
let entryPoint (_: string[], mainWindow: Window) =
        Program.mkProgram init update bindings
        |> Program.runWindowWithConfig
            { ElmConfig.Default with LogTrace = true; Measure = true; MeasureLimitMs = 1 }
            mainWindow
```

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it has been replaced.  I replaced it with a setting function on `WpfProgram` for each field of the config.  This design allows adding a new value to configure in a backwards compatible manner.  See [a sample](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/master/src/Samples/SingleCounter.Core/Program.fs).

Comment: "namespace Serilog" is not defined?  Thanks.

Comment: Oops...found it. It is it's own nuget package.